# SQL Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql

I am trying to set a column in a table to say 'no date set' if the column in the DB has a date value as NULL. If the column has a date value then i want to display it. This SQL is all within a SPROC and then the values are passed to the application

DB Values are of type DATETYPE,NULL

[image]

Here is what i have tried so far

```
,CASE WHEN [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate] IS NULL THEN 'no date set' ELSE [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate] END AS [expiry]
```

results in [image]

,COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS DATETIME), 'no date set'), [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate]          AS [expiry]

Results in a conversion error.

This works but all null values are blank in my table.

```
,[TB_EVNTEXP].StartDate]                    AS [cardexpiry]
```

Spent way to much time on this now and could do with a helpful hand :)

Cheers
Paul

Comment: When its like this it works ,[TB_EVNTEXP].StartDate]  AS [cardexpiry] but when its like this it fails ,ISNULL([TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate], 'no date set')         AS [cardexpiry]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using SQL Server, which does not allow you mix string with Date format.

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate] END AS [expiry] 
FROM
```

Or you need convert the date to a varchar to mix it with empty values:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate] IS NULL THEN 'not set' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, [TB_EVNTEXP].[StartDate]) END AS [expiry] 
FROM
```

Comment: BOOM!! Thanks so much :) exactly what i needed! convert to a varchar. thanks Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is where your error occurs:

```
COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS DATETIME), 'no date set'),
```

This is logically the same, and it runs.

```
 COALESCE(NULL, 'no date set'),
```

or better yet,

```
'no date set'
```